# Maven-dependency-plugin and annotations with SOURCE RetentionPolicy

Tags: java, maven, maven-dependency-plugin, auto-value

In a mvn project where I am utilizing `maven-dependency-plugin` to detect unused dependencies, there is seemingly no dependency `scope` I can specify for Google's AutoValue (`com.google.auto.value:auto-value`) to that will convince the plugin that the dependency is being used in spite of the fact that annotations from the package are being used (e.g. `@AutoValue`) and the project won't build if `auto-value` is excluded.

Now one solution is simply adding a configuration entry to my plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <usedDependencies>
            <usedDependency>com.google.auto.value:auto-value</usedDependency>
        </usedDependencies>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But I would be curious to know whether it's possible to configure either the `maven-dependency-plugin` or the `dependency` entry for `auto-value` in a way that would detect usage of the dependency per its annotations?

My suspicion is that this isn't possible because the `RetentionPolicy` of the annotations I'm using from auto-value are of `RetentionPolicy.SOURCE` and are discarded by the compiler.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, your suspicion is correct. The `maven-dependency-plugin` documentation specifically lists this as a concern here for source level annotations: http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-dependency-analyzer/

> **Warning**: Analysis is not done at source but bytecode level, then some cases are not detected (constants, annotations with source-only retention, links in javadoc) which can lead to wrong result if they are the only use of a dependency.

You can force `AutoValue` as `used` with `usedDependencies` as you have in your example or use the `ignoredUnusedDeclaredDependencies` configuration instead (which is what I did recently).

I don't believe it is possible to configure the dependency section to avoid this because maven doesn't provide a scope level that is compile only. I mark `AutoValue` with the `provided` scope to keep it out of any shaded jars I might make.

Lastly, you could write (or find if it exists) a custom dependency analyzer that takes source level annotations into account. See the documentation here http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html#analyzer. Probably not worth the effort.